# Is the stackoverflow Documentation feature going to be rolled out to other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

See the announcement blog post [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/), and read the tour [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation).

I'm a relative newcomer to Ham SE, but I can already think of some ways documentation might be really useful to us.  For example, there seem to be fairly regular questions about lightning protection, and a good number of well-thought-out and well-documented answers.  They could all be gathered together on one Documentation page, which could be more broadly focused on the principles and practices of lightning protection, rather than answering one specific question about the best way to ground one particular rig.

I could see this feature being useful for a lot of other areas, including (for example):

- How to get licensed
- The differences between amateur and other radio services
- General tips/questions to consider when purchasing a radio
- Basic principles of antenna design/installation/safety (obviously a very large topic)

From reading the site self-evaluation posts, it seems one of the main concerns for the last few years has been that we don't have enough questions.  Perhaps this kind of documentation would increase our visibility and help with that problem by improving our general reputation as a good resource for getting questions about radio answered.

Answer (score 4):

> Is the stackoverflow Documentation feature going to be rolled out to other SE sites?

I haven't found an official word on the matter yet, but my understanding of the situation is:

**Documentation is highly experimental, and it's far too early to think of expanding the scope of it. We have to see if it works at all first.**

> From reading the site self-evaluation posts, it seems one of the main concerns for the last few years has been that we don't have enough questions.

Don't worry about that too much. At the time of those remarks, we of ham.stackexchange.com were concerned about the [criterion of a good rate of questions on a beta site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43029/amateur-radio). Since then, Stack Exchange has recognized that [a site can be small and yet ‘healthy’](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites). We may not *graduate* (lose the ‘beta’ label) any time soon, but that's okay.

(Oh, and the site self-evaluation process [has been shut down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261601/shutting-down-recurring-community-self-evaluations) because it was not producing relevant information.)

Comment: These are all very good points!  Good to see that SE overall, and the mods of this community, have been open to being flexible and keeping eyes on the prize of good content.  I'll hold out hope that documentation gets rolled out to a wider audience eventually; I think we could do some cool stuff with it.  Interested to know if other, more seasoned Ham SE users agree with that.  Is our site particularly well-suited to the Documentation feature?

Answer (score 2):

As an SE Community Manager, I wanted to stop by to say that Kevin's answer is right on point.

To reiterate, the day may come when Documentation is available for other SE sites -- I think a lot of us around the company would love that! -- but Docs *just* launched, and right now all our focus is going into making sure the existing product works well.